# HTTP post xml data .net4 c#

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0

I am trying to post a xml data

Current I am doing this. requestXml is XmlDocument.

```
var connectionString = new Uri(SystemPropertyManager.Connexall_ConnectionString);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
request.Timeout = 10000;
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml.ToString());
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse response;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

To test this I wrote an MVC application

```
// POST api/Contact
public SomeObject[] Post([FromBody]string message)
{
    return new SomeObject[];
}
```

I am able to call the post method but the message is always null. What am I doing wrong. Since the mvc web api application is just a test application I can't add message identifier in the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code says that you want to receive a .net String object serialized as XML or JSON.

```
// POST api/Contact
public SomeObject[] Post([FromBody]string message)
{
    return new SomeObject[];
}
```

That would look something like

```
<string xmlns="...">some string</string>
```

To read the string as XML, you can either do

```
// POST api/Contact
public SomeObject[] Post([FromBody]XElement message)
{
    return new SomeObject[];
}
```

or

```
// POST api/Contact
public async SomeObject[] Post()
{
    string body = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Parse string to XML
    return new SomeObject[];
}
```

Comment: I tried this
// POST api/Contact
`public SomeObject[] Post([FromBody]XElement message)
{
    return new SomeObject[];
}`
but this request kept giving me 500 server error.
Then I tried 
`public SomeObject[] Post([FromBody]XmlDocument message)
{
    return new SomeObject[];
}`
The message variable is null in this request.

Then I tried 
`public void Post([FromBody]XmlDocument message)
        {
            var body = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;            
        }`

The value of body is "em.Xml.XmlDocument"

Comment: @neo I just tried it with XElement on a freshly created Web API project based on the default template and it worked fine.  Are there any more details in your 500 error?

Comment: System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: nevermind. It was my bad. I was sending XmlDocument.ToString()
I changed it to XmlDocument.InnerXml and it worked.